# Xcode - Parse & facebook header file(SDK) error

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform, sdk

I want to use both Parse & facebook SDK's with my app, I did everything and added every library from both Parse & facebook and edited my `App Delegate` file according to the docs, but I keep getting errors in my bridging-header file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> 
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Error:

```
'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
```

The errors are not specific to any statement, I delete one and the next gets an error. This file is called `"MyApp-Bridging-Header.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to add the AVFoundation and CoreLocation frameworks to your target. Then delete the derived data from your project by going to window-->projects. Do this then clean and build your project.

Sidenote: Make sure when you type in "#import " the FBSDKCoreKit is autofilled in after you have typed a few letters. If the framework has been added already, it should give you the option to autofill the import. If it is not added this may not show up, and if this is the case, make sure your framework is added to your project in finder.

Hope this helps!